# Ggplot2 plot a subset of time series lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

My question is related to the second answer to this question and also my previous question (posted below).

[Proper way to plot multiple data series in ggplot with custom colors, legend etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688204/proper-way-to-plot-multiple-data-series-in-ggplot-with-custom-colors-legend-etc)

How is it possible to plot a subset of lines according to user's needs (i.e. first and third, all four etc.)? Currently I am using base `plot()` and would like to change to `ggplot2` solution. I need to address that the time series have uneven lengths, as in the original question. I was experimenting with the syntax simialr to the following, but without success:

```
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line(aes(y = y[dat$grp == "a"], colour=grp)) + geom_point()

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (20): y, colour, x
```

P.S.: For those interested, this is what I am trying to do (I keep my previous question updated, however I am the only one posting there):
I am trying to build this functionality into my Shiny application. I.e. user chooses a number of parameters, which I convert to a set of IDs which correspond to a subset of time series in my dataframe and the plot outputs the chosen subset of lines.

[Shiny + ggplot2: plotting a number of lines in one graph based on user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319541/shiny-ggplot2-plotting-a-number-of-lines-in-one-graph-based-on-user-input/41485451#41485451)

Comment: Use `subset(dat, grp == "a")` as the data instead of messing around inside the `aes`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works for a reasonable number of lines. Now I have hundreds of lines to plot, i.e. hundreds of conditions of a form `subset(dat, grp == "a" | grp == "b" | ... )`. Is there a more elegant, easier solution to subset, eg. something similar to specifying `grp == c("a", "b", ...)`?

Comment: Many thanks. It is for people like you that StackOverflow is a great place. If you want to write an answer, I will be glad to accept it.

Comment: You're welcome. There is probably a duplicate somewhere, but I'm on my phone so I can't find it.

Comment: It is possible. I spent a lot of time searching, so I just created this question